# Как клонировать LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, клонирование

Есть LinearLayout, в который вложено несколько LinearLayouts, Textviews и некот.других views. При клике по этому LinearLayout нужно создать точно такой же LinearLayout со всеми вложенными view. Как это сделать?

Comment: Как создаётся уже имеющийся Контейнер с разметкой? Если он в xml определён - то просто делаете ещё один. Если программно - вынесите код в метод и вызовите его. Т.е. ответ - как создаёте первый так и второй создавайте

Comment: View в андроиде не клонируются. Придется создавать новый вручную.

Comment: Думаю такое можно сделать с помощью `RecyclerView`

Comment: понятно, если View  не клонируются, тогда буду искать какой-то другой способ решения.